# What is wrong with this proof of $e \le 2$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, fake-proofs

For every $n$, $e \le \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

$$
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \frac{n}{1!}\times\frac{1}{n}
+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\times\frac{1}{n^2}+\ldots+ \frac{n!}{n!}\times\frac{1}{n^n}
\le 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}\le1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}
$$

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, we get
$$
e \le e \le 2
$$

$2$ is the sum of the geometric series on the right side of the given inequality. And we get $e$ in the middle because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1!}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ is not true.

Comment: The last inequality on the first line is definitely questionable.

Comment: You are missing a $1$ in the final sum: you should end up with $e \le 3$.

Comment: Congrats, you proved $e<3$.

Comment: I thought $e$ was more than $2$. I am so confused about the question

Comment: @rostader Since $e>2$, the OP is wondering how they could have proved $e\le2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missed a $1$ in your sum.  Properly,

$1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+...<1\color{blue}{+1}+(1/2)+(1/2^2)+...$

Thus the comparison sum is $1+2=3$ instead of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Using this method (with a little generalization), you can obtain tight bounds on $e$.

For instance,

$$\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}<e<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}\left(1+\frac15+\frac1{5^2}+\cdots\right)$$

$$\frac{65}{24}<e<\frac{87}{32}.$$

Comment: With full generalization of your method, $[1+(1/1!)+...(1/n!)]<e<[1+(1/1!)+...+[(n+1)/(nn!)]]$.

Answer (score 1):

The final inequality is false. In particular, the second sumand of the left hand side is $\frac{1}{1!}$, while the second sumand of the right hand side is $\frac12$, which is a *smaller* number.